# Strange error when developing a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I tried to follow [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwecNcdAUaY) (on YouTube).

However I receive this extremely strange error which I can't understand.

I've included an image to show the error:

[image: image-of-error]

I've checked my code 100 times and have compared it with the tutorial code, and I think the error is in `index.php`.

**CODE PHP:**

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <title><?php bloginfo('title')?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url')?>"
              <?php wp_head()?>
        </head>
        <body>

        <header>
            <h1><?php bloginfo('name')?></h1>
        </header>


    <div id="container">
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php get_header()?>
<div>
    <?php while (have_posts()):the_post()?>
    <h2><?php the_title()?></h2>
    <?php the_content(__('contie_reading'));?>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</div>

<?php get_footer()?>
<?php get_sidebar()?>
```

**FOOTER.PHP**

```
</div>

<footer>
   <?=date('y')?> Copyright Never
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you know where does this matter? I searched solving and unfortunately I have not found.

Comment: It seems like, that some of your javascript snippets aren't correctly included. Look up in the wp_head, because the javascripts are included there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a broken link tag in your header.php file.

Change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url')?>"
```

To:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url')?>">
```

While this corrects the issue at hand I'd advise you to find a different tutorial.

There are multiple issues with the approach you're taking such as including stylesheets in the head section instead of enqueueing them, using PHP short tags, placing the sidebar after your footer, etc.